# Servername regex Nginx with proxy_pass not working

Tags: regex, apache, nginx, proxy

I want my server to listen to all requests from mon1.example.com/mon2.example.com/mon3.example.com/... and proxy it to an internal IP.

I made this simple configuration in Nginx

```
upstream supervisor {
        server 127.0.0.1:9001 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^mon(\d+)\.example\.com$;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

However this doesn't seem to work. I've read somewhere that you can't combine a regex severname with a proxy pass in Nginx, is this correct? And what are the alternatives?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Do you have DNS records for `mon1.example.com`/etc.?

Comment: Yes I have CNAME records that point to that server. if i change the servername regex into mon2.example.com (no regex) it works. Now I have 'page does not exist'.

Comment: Do you have other server blocks with regexp or wildcards?

Comment: Yes, but to diffrent domains. i have one *.stage.example.com for example

Comment: Well, check if one of them matches `mon1.example.com` somehow. Because nginx checks wildcard matches before regexps. See priority order at the end of http://nginx.org/r/server_name

Answer (score -1):

According to nginx [doco](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html);

> They may be defined using exact names, wildcard names, or regular
>   expressions:

```
server {
     listen       80;
     server_name  example.org  www.example.org;
     ... }

 server {
     listen       80;
     server_name  *.example.org;
     ... }

 server {
     listen       80;
     server_name  mail.*;
     ... }

 server {
     listen       80;
     server_name  ~^(?<user>.+)\.example\.net$;
     ... }
```

**Update:**
Specifying multiple hostnames separated by commas works as well.

Comment: I'm aware, then why is my regex not working? (I have tested adding mon2.servername.com as static and that works, so it should be picked up by the regex as well)

Comment: Can you try including it in quotes

Comment: No success, 'page does not exist' as before

Comment: do you need www in fron to access your servers? if so you can try including ^www. Another thing is trying specifying each hostname separated by space

Comment: Thanks, spaces work and will do for now, however in the future I'd like to get that regex working though. Adding www\. didn't work